# Delete cookie not working if cookie is set to all subdomains on same domain

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, unset

I am creating cookie like that:

```
Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('cookie_name', 'cookie_value', 60, '/', '.domain.com'));
```

As i understand, cookie is set to domain globally, i mean, that this cookie will work with subdomains also. For example: `example.domain.com`

However, i can't delete it, if i am initiating deletion on subdomain.

```
Cookie::queue(Cookie::forget('cookie_name'));
```

How can i do that?

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Cookie::queue('cookie_name', null, -1);
return Redirect::route('your_route');
```

Comment: But this one worked: ``Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('cookie_name', NULL, -999999, '/', '.domain.com'));``

Comment: Confirmed `Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('cookie_name', NULL, -999999, '/', '.domain.com'));` is the fix. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to remove the cookie

```
$cookie = Cookie::forget('cookie_name', null, '.domain.com');
return response()->json(['success' => true, 'message' => 'You are successfully logged out.'])->withCookie($cookie);
```